# Is there a better selection of datastructures and algorithms for this problem?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures

For the following problem please suggest better solution (in terms of time complexcity). My approach I have explained at the last.

There is a file that has records in following format:-
RecordType;Symbol;price;id;parentId

Sample file looks like -

```
RecordType;Symbol;price;id;parentId

 - A;BANK_X;20;2345;0
 - A;BANK_Y;30;2346;0
 - A;BANK_Z;40;2347;0
 - M;BANK_X;50;2348;2345
 - M;BANK_Y;10;2349;2346 
 - A;BANK_X;20;2350;0 
 - A;BANK_E;40;2351;0 
 - M;BANK_X;45;2352;2345 
 - M;BANK_X;20;2353;2350
```

Such a file contains millions of records. Objective is to write a efficient C++ program to split file into multiple files such that each smaller file contains Y number of records, where Y is an integer number provided as input.

Points to remember:

- Every record has unique id (i.e. second last field in the record)
- For a symbol matching A and M records should be in the same smaller file.

For example, if example file is splited into files containing minimum 2 rows, then following records should be in one file:

```
 - A;BANK_X;20;2345;0
 - M;BANK_X;50;2348;2345
 - M;BANK_X;45;2352;2345
```

My approach to solve problem:

1. Data structure used:

   - Queue: This will have objects in which key will be id (those are parents) and value in the object will be a vector that will have list of children.
   - Unordered_map 1: Key: id (i.e. ids whose record has value 0 in the last field), value: string (i.e. record of that id read from file)
   - Unordered_map 2: Key: id (i.e. ids whose record has NON 0 value in the last field), value: string (i.e. record of that id read from file)
2. Algorithm:

   - Read file line by line
   - Parse last 2 fields of record
   - Check if id is parent (i.e. if last field of record is 0)
     If YES: 
     create object{id, vactor< int >} put in the queue
     Add id and string record to unordered_map 1
     If NO:
     Search parent id in the queue and add child id in the vector (This can be made constant time search)
     Add id and string record to unordered_map 2
   - Perform above steps till end of file.
   - Now start popping the queue and for each id (that is parent) get the record string from Unordered_map 1 write in a new file,
     Also for it's children (which are available in vector) get the record string from Unordered_map 2 write in the file.
     Here I will check for minimum rows.
   - Based on the value of Y, get the record for ids (parent) and children from unsorted_map and write to new files.

If I consider sample file mentioned in the statement, after applying my algo data structures will have following values:-

```
Queue< int, std::vector < int> >: [ {2345, <2348, 2352>}, {2346, <2349>}, {2347, <empty>}, {2350, <2353>}, {2351, <empty>}]
Unordered_map 1 < int, std::string >: [{2345, "A;BANK_X;20;2345;0"}, {2346, "A;BANK_Y;30;2346;0"}, {2347, "A;BANK_Z;40;2347;0"}, {2350, "A;BANK_X;20;2350;0"}, {2351, "A;BANK_E;40;2351;0"}]
Unordered_map 2 < int, std::string >: [{2348, "M;BANK_X;50;2348;2345"}, {2349, "M;BANK_Y;10;2349;2346"}, {2352, "M;BANK_X;45;2352;2345"}, {2353, "M;BANK_X;20;2353;2350"}]
```

Comment: What is the role of the `parent id` ? Does a parent symbol have to be in the same file as its children ?

Comment: @fjardon: In any record if parent id is 0, means id of that row is parent. If parent id of a record is non zero means id of this row is child and it parent is mentioned by parent id in the same row. Children symbols (i.e. records) should be in the same file as parent.

Comment: Can a child be a parent for another child ?

Comment: No, a child can not be parent of another child.

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of children for a parent ?

Comment: Is the number of items in each file a hard constraint ? Is it possible to create files with more or less items than `Y`. Or are we sure that the exact splitting is always possible ?

Comment: No, there is no limit on number of children of a parent. It is possible to have more items (e.g. children of parent are more than or equal to Y). Less item only possible if Y is greater than no of records in file.

Answer (score 1):

Following statements from your question:

> *"Such a file contains millions of records."*
>   *"Every record has unique id (i.e. second last field in the record)"*

.. assert me to advise you to use SQL database. With that, you may keep everything in single file for ease of access. You can efficiently `select, insert, update, delete` in future without loosing the flexibility you get from day 1.

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) is indeed a lightweight alternative.

Comment: @Abhishek SQLite is a C library. You can include it into your C++ program, there are a number of "OO" C++ wrappers for SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using vector and map. declare a vector[SIZE_OF_SYMBLE].map symbols with integers.then each time you get an entry, first get the mapped int value for the symbol from map and push the entry to that vector.

```
struct record{string recordType;char symbol;double price;int id;};
map<char,int> symbmol_to_int;
vector<record> piles[SIZE_OF_SYMBOL];
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I came up with a better solution. Since it looks like the ids are in sorted order, you can write to the file right after the process of each line. For each child record, just write to the file where its parent is at. Only need to remember you write the parent record to which file.

```
unordered_map<int, int> id_to_file_id;
```

---

Actually, you don't need to store the whole string in a map, you only need to store which line it is at. This would save half of the space you used.

And use a data structure like this:

```
unordered_map<int, int> id_to_line;
map<int, vector<int>> groups; // map<parent_id, vector<child_id>>
```

Comment: Thanks StillFantasy, but if I store line numbers then to get actual line I need to read file again right ? And this time I need to read file at random locations (based on the line numbers), isn't it make my program too slow ?

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. I changed it a little bit.

Comment: @ StillFantasy, challenge is not to save memory. Challenge is to get most efficient solution for millions of record. You need to split file into multiple files based on the input number Y. Let's say file has 1 million record and first 1000 records are for parents only and children records after that (You never know the sequence). And value of Y is 10, how will you split file while reading it. Up to 1001th record even you don't have idea about children.